# Given a sequence of head to tail vectors forming a closed loop, how can I determine if they form a knot?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, random-walk, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Consider if we have some sequence of vectors placed head to tail which form a closed loop. How can one determine whether they form a loop?

We assume that it is given that the vectors close, that is their vector sum is zero, and that the piecewise curve they form is non-intersecting. If it helps, we can also assume they have the same length. An example is shown here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp26t.jpg

An example of how such configurations might be generated is through self-avoiding random walks on a lattice, where each vector represents a single "step".

EDIT:

Okay so clearly this problem is not nearly as trivial as I had first thought. Some more details:

I am considering loops that are generated by a sequence of edges on a lattice. For example, we could take a cubic lattice, although in my case the lattice is non-Bravais. By construction, the loop does not self-intersect, as would be the case for a self-avoiding random walk. My idea was simply to determine whether or not the loop is the unknot or not (I use the loops for other purposes but thought it might be an interesting research thread to pursue to study their knotted-ness).

Comment: How do you define a "knot" in this context?  Are you just asking if they form a knot different than the unknot (*which is still technically an example of a knot*)?  This is one of the classic problems that knot theory tries to answer, the final result being *it is hard to be sure*.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for pointing that out, of course in this context I do mean a knot other than the unknot.

Comment: I haven't heard of a result showing it is undecidable, but then again the last knot theory book I read I had only properly made it through the front half and it is probably 20 years old at this point (Adams, The Knot Book).  I could believe that there have been significant advancements in that time.  The last results I had read were the existence of various knot invariant polynomials that one could calculate, and if the polynomials are different between two knots then you can be sure the knots themselves are different.  If the polynomials are the same however that isn't enough to conclude.

Comment: Related: [Wikipedia - Unknotting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknotting_problem).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a well known currently active research topic.  Brute force algorithms exist, however it remains unknown whether the problem can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: @JMoravitz It's not expected to be polynomial time, and I don't think "brute force" really explains the known algorithms. One way is to find a homomorphism of the fundamental group of the knot complement to $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ whose image is not just diagonal matrices, and one exists if and only if the knot is knotted. This amounts to solving a system of polynomial equations. Practically speaking, computing the Jones polynomial is sufficient, especially if the knot in question has at most 23 crossings, since the conjecture that it is an unknot detector has been verified at least to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically speaking, this is not quite so bad as others are making it out to be.  There is a conjecture with much computational evidence that the Jones polynomial is an unknot detector (it's true, at least, for knot diagrams with up to 23 crossings).  The Jones polynomial isn't so difficult to compute, and, assuming the conjecture, the given knot is the unknot if and only if the Jones polynomial is $1$.

For knots on a lattice, what you have to do is find a knot diagram.  If you choose a random projection direction, almost surely the projection will be in *general position*: no two vertices project to the same point, no vertex projects onto the interior of any segment, and the projections of any two segments are *transverse*, i.e., when they intersect, they are not collinear.  While extremely unlikely, if you find the projection is not in general position, you can try projecting in another random direction.

From here, for each pair of intersecting projected segments, you figure out which is 'over' and which is 'under'.  It's convenient to then store the result in oriented PD format (see the [Knot Atlas wiki](http://katlas.org/wiki/Planar_Diagrams) and maybe [this page about representing knots on computers](https://math.berkeley.edu/~kmill/2019_8_25/gauss_dt_codes.html)).  If you know how to read Mathematica, I once wrote a little bit about computing Jones polynomials in this answer: [Software for computing virtual knot invariants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753837/software-for-computing-virtual-knot-invariants/3135284#3135284)

(I'm not just speaking theoretically that it's plausible to go through all this.  A colleague of mine did the very same calculations for studying whether certain orbits in a discrete vector field in a triangulation of $S^3$ might be knotted.)

If you want to be absolutely sure your knot is unknotted, you can use Dynnikov's algorithm, for example.  It's very slow, but it's [not so hard to implement](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/30292/knot-or-not/79132#79132).

Comment: thanks! This is very useful information, and I use MMA all the time

Comment: @Kai By the way, you do not actually need to keep track of orientations, and it's fine just using `X` objects for crossings and `P` objects for paths.  Then you calculate `kb` for the Kauffman bracket, and if it is $(-A^3)^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, your knot is conjectured to be unknotted.  The orientations are used to pin down a normalization using the writhe of the diagram.

Comment: thanks, I am not sure if this project is going to be worth the time to dig into right now, but if I do I will definitely be coming back to this answer!

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you are asking is for an overview of the theory of knots, which is rather too broad.

[This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknotting_problem) contains a brief overview of what's known about the unknotting problem, which is the problem of algorithmically determining whether a given knot is an unknot. In short, it is algorithmically decidable, and the decision problem is known to be NP-complete.

For a more in depth look at knot theory, look at [this other wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory), or better pick up a good textbook such as [Rolfsen's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory#CITEREFRolfsen1976). You seem to know what the correct tags are, i.e. group-theory, knot-invariants, etc., and you'll find lots of information about those topics of you follow the links given..

Comment: While the unknotting decision problem in an arbitrary 3-manifold is $\text{NP}$-complete (Agol-Hass-Thurston 2006), in $S^3$ it's in $\text{NP}\cap\text{co-NP}$, a class that's unknown whether it intersects $\text{NP}$-hard. I think Lackenby has a quasi-polynomial-time algorithm for unknot detection in $S^3$.